Ruby Regex - Match exactly N backticks with exactly N backticks
I think I have found the solution to a GitHub issue, but it involves a bit of advanced RegEx in Ruby. (I rarely worked with Ruby and I wouldn't call myself a professional in RegEx). The problem is that when you have let's say 5 (anything above 3) opening backticks then the parser encounters 3 backticks, it will automatically close the code block. Basically the code is as follows:
  def escape_liquid_tags_in_codeblock(content)
      # Escape codeblocks, code spans, and inline code
      content.gsub(/[[:space:]]*~{3}.*?~{3}|[[:space:]]*`{3}.*?`{3}|`{2}.+?`{2}|`{1}.+?`{1}/m) do |codeblock|
        codeblock.gsub!("{% endraw %}", "{----% endraw %----}")
        codeblock.gsub!("{% raw %}", "{----% raw %----}")
        if codeblock.match?(/[[:space:]]*`{3}/)
          "\n{% raw %}\n#{codeblock}\n{% endraw %}\n"
        else
          "{% raw %}#{codeblock}{% endraw %}"
        end
      end
    end


First of all, a block of code in markdown can be at least 3 backticks (`) or tildes (~), not necessarily exactly 3. I believe I know the solution for this problem, but I just need to know if it is possible to write something like this?
[[:space:]]*`{N}.*?`{N}

where N can be any number, but of course, the number of beginning and closing ticks have to be equal.
I also believe that the if statement should be {3,} not {3}. If anyone can tell me how to have a regex of N beginning backticks and N closing backticks that would be great. I would also be open to any suggestions on how to go about the issue.
I tried ChatGPTing it, but ChatGPT didn't give me the right RegEx if it is even possible.

Maybe something like this /(\{3,})(.*[^`])(\1)/m`? Basic Example

I agree with your "at least" statement:

Change {3} to {3,} to match at least 3 characters.

Next, capture groups can apply here too:

Change ...{3,}.*?{3,}... to: ...(`{3,}).*?\1

This will capture the backtick itself and the repeat, and then match that capture on the closing end.
We can then simplify the match to a character range to eliminate the big top-level "or":

Replace (`{3,}) with ([~`]{3,})

Then, depending on your preference, we can replace [[:space:]] with \s. This reduces the regex to:
/\s*([~`]{3,})(.*)?\1/m

I added a capture for the content because that's usually desired, and your m flag allows matches to span multiple lines. Here is a link to this in an online Ruby Regex Evaluator:
https://rubular.com/r/lOCj3z2a23CApH

All that's left then is to add comments.

Oh jeez, you're right. I didn't look at the posted code close enough when I copy/pasted it.  I'll update my answer. I also looked at the mentioned github issue. The problem is that someone wants to put triple-backticks in a backtick'ed example text, and believe they can do that by using (eg) 5 backticks in the outer block. Apparently github supports this.

If I understand it correctly I think it should be more like (\{3,})([^`].*?)(\1)with thes` flag. Example
